# Check if value of one array matches with key of another array - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have two array as :

```
<?php

$arr1 = ["","2nd Level","11' Ceilings","1016 SF","1168SF","1186-1204SF","11ft Ceilings","1211-1226SF","14 Square Footage","15 Square Footage","16 Square Footage","17 Square Footage","18 Square Footage","19 Square Footage","20 Square Footage","21 Square Footage","2nd","3rd","4th","538-541SF","543-564SF","547-557SF","5th","614-619SF","629-639SF","6th","701-724SF","7th Fl PH1A","8th Street View","905-1046SF","Additional Closets","Alley View","Alley View 2","Alley\/Wall View 65 Stack","Bradley","City View","Corner Unit","Courtyard View","Dbl Balcony","Double Windows","Eisen 1","Eisen 2","Eisen 3","Eisen 4","End Unit","Goodwin","Grand Ave View","Int Corner 2","Interior Corner","Large Storage","Lg. Balcony","Loss Leader","Loss Leader2","Loss Leader3","Loss Leader4","Nielson 1","Nielson 2","Nielson 3","Nielson 4","Nielson 5","Nielson 6","Olive Street View","Partial Courtyard View","Partial Pool View","Patio","Ph1a","Ph1b","Ph2","Ph3","Pol. Concrete","Pool View","Regular Balcony","Rent","Sm. Balcony","Small Storage","Top Floor","View 4","View 5","Walk-in Closet","Walker","murphy bed"];

$arr2 = array (
  '1st Floor' => 375,
  '2nd Floor' => 375,
  '3rd Floor' => 375,
  '4th Floor' => 375,
  '5th Floor' => 375,
  'Fireplace' => 384,
  'RPRenovation' => 380,
  'Renovated' => 380,
  'Rent' => 381,
  'Test' => 383,
  'FEAT-ADA' => 368,
  'FEAT-GAR 1C' => 384,
  'FEAT-W/D' => 384,
  'FEAT-YARD' => 384,
  'FL-LC--1B' => 375,
  'FL-LC--2B' => 375,
  'FL-LC-All-1B' => 375,
  'FL-LC-All-2B' => 375,
  'FL-P1--1B' => 375,
  'FL-P1--2B' => 375,
  'LOC-NEG' => 379,
  'LOC-OTHER' => 379,
  'LVL-1ST-1B' => 375,
  'LVL-1ST-2B' => 375,
  'LVL-TOP-1B' => 375,
  'LVL-TOP-2B' => 375,
  'R-LC-DMD-1B' => 375,
  'R-LC-DMD-2B' => 379,
  'R-LC-GLD-1B' => 379,
  'R-LC-GLD-2B' => 379,
  'R-LC-PLT-1B' => 379,
  'R-LC-PLT-2B' => 379,
  'base rent adj' => 381,
  'Balcony' => 370,
  '1/2 Bath' => 371,
  '2018 Bathroom Upgrade' => 371,
  '2018 Kitchen Upgrade' => 378,
  '2018 Laminate Countertops' => 377,
  '2018 Stainless Steel Appliance' => 378,
  '2018 Subway Tile' => 377,
  '2018 Vinyl Plank Flooring' => 377,
  'Accessible Unit' => 368,
  'Bonus Room' => 382,
  'Bottom Floor' => 375,
  'Building B' => 379,
  'Building D' => 379,
  'Building E' => 379,
  'Bump Out' => 384,
  'Cinderblock Walls' => 384,
  'Corner unit' => 374,
  'Electric Included With Rent' => 381,
  'Extra Storage' => 373,
  'French Doors' => 384,
  'Hardwood Floors' => 377,
  'Laundry Room' => 379,
  'Non-Operable Windows' => 387,
  'Platform with Storage' => 373,
  'Square Feet: 1000 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1008 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1030 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1108 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1110 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1121 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1123 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1130 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1170 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1175 (2BD) Base' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1220 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1237 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1280 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1309 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 1342 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 580 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 583 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 691 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 696 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 740 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 748 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 789 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 792 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 805 (1BD) Base' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 847 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 848 (2BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 880 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 912 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 974 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Square Feet: 987 (1BD)' => 382,
  'Stainless steel appliances' => 378,
  'Standard Townhome' => 383,
  'Top Floor' => 375,
  'View - Motorcycle Parking' => 386,
  'View - Parking' => 386,
  'View - Partial River' => 386,
  'View - Railroad Tracks' => 386,
  'View - River' => 386,
  'View - Service Area' => 386,
  'Windows Do Not Open' => 387,
  'Ada' => 368,
  'accessible' => 368,
  'handicap' => 368,
  'Affordable' => 369,
  'BMR' => 369,
  'Bond' => 369,
  'HAP' => 369,
  'balconies' => 370,
  'Patio' => 370,
  'Terrace' => 370,
  'Lanai' => 370,
  'Bathroom' => 371,
  'bathrooms' => 371,
  'Shower' => 371,
  'showers' => 371,
  'Vanity' => 371,
  'sink' => 371,
  'Ceiling' => 372,
  'ceilings' => 372,
  'vaulted' => 372,
  'Storage' => 373,
  'Closet' => 373,
  'closets' => 373,
  'Walk-in' => 373,
  'Linen' => 373,
  'Corner' => 374,
  'corners' => 374,
  'Level' => 375,
  'levels' => 375,
  '1st' => 375,
  '2nd' => 375,
  '3rd' => 375,
  '4th' => 375,
  '5th' => 375,
  '6th' => 375,
  '7th' => 375,
  '8th' => 375,
  '9th' => 375,
  '10th' => 375,
  '11th' => 375,
  '12th' => 375,
  '13th' => 375,
  '14th' => 375,
  '15th' => 375,
  '16th' => 375,
  '17th' => 375,
  '18th' => 375,
  '19th' => 375,
  '20th' => 375,
  'Layout' => 376,
  'layouts' => 376,
  'floor plan' => 376,
  'floorplan' => 376,
  'Finish' => 377,
  'finishes' => 377,
  'Flooring' => 377,
  'Wood' => 377,
  'Plank' => 377,
  'Vinyl' => 377,
  'Kitchen' => 378,
  'kitchens' => 378,
  'Stainless' => 378,
  'Appliance' => 378,
  'appliances' => 378,
  'Location' => 379,
  'locations' => 379,
  'End' => 379,
  'Reno' => 380,
  'renovation' => 380,
  'renovations' => 380,
  'Platinum' => 380,
  'Silver' => 380,
  'Gold' => 380,
  'Upgrade' => 380,
  'upgrades' => 380,
  'Rents' => 381,
  'Discount' => 381,
  'Loss Leader' => 381,
  'SF' => 382,
  'sqft' => 382,
  'sq ft' => 382,
  'square feet' => 382,
  'square foot' => 382,
  'sq feet' => 382,
  'square footage' => 382,
  'Feature' => 384,
  'features' => 384,
  'W/D' => 384,
  'WD' => 384,
  'Washer' => 384,
  'Dryer' => 384,
  'Garage' => 384,
  'Garages' => 384,
  'Driveway' => 384,
  'view' => 386,
  'views' => 386,
  'Window' => 387,
  'windows' => 387,
);
```

### Requirements:

## Check Condition

1) Check if any value of `$arr1` is in the key of `$arr2`.
2) IF the value don't match exactly, we need to split words from value of `$arr1` and check if all word matches and have the same value.

i.e, for example

1. check if `2nd level` matches with any key in `$arr2`.
2. if `2nd level` do not fine any matches split `2nd level` to `2nd` and `level`. If both `2nd` and `level` matches to key with same value.

In this case both `2nd` and `level` has value `375` this means this should be considered a match. In case if `2nd` had `375` and `level` had `376`, this would not be a match.

### If Matched:

Above I mentioned two ways which could be considered as match, and if it find the match, the result be written in new `$result` array with the index of `$arr1`.

For example: if `$res[0]` find no match, then `$res[0] = ''`. Similarly `$res[1] = '375' and so on.

For instance: The `$res` array could be like:

```
$res = array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '375',
  2 => '',
  3 => '',
  4 => '',
  5 => '',
  6 => '',
  7 => '',
  8 => '',
  9 => '',
  10 => '',
  11 => '',
  12 => '',
  13 => '',
  14 => '',
  15 => '',
  16 => 375,
  17 => 375,
  18 => 375,
  19 => '',
  20 => '',
  21 => '',
  22 => 375,
  23 => '',
  24 => '',
  25 => 375,
  26 => '',
  27 => '',
  28 => '',
  29 => '',
  30 => '',
  31 => '',
  32 => '',
  33 => '',
  34 => '',
  35 => '',
  36 => 374,
  37 => '',
  38 => '',
  39 => '',
  40 => '',
  41 => '',
  42 => '',
  43 => '',
  44 => '',
  45 => '',
  46 => '',
  47 => '',
  48 => '',
  49 => '',
  50 => '',
  51 => 381,
  52 => '',
  53 => '',
  54 => '',
  55 => '',
  56 => '',
  57 => '',
  58 => '',
  59 => '',
  60 => '',
  61 => '',
  62 => '',
  63 => '',
  64 => 370,
  65 => '',
  66 => '',
  67 => '',
  68 => '',
  69 => '',
  70 => '',
  71 => '',
  72 => 381,
  73 => '',
  74 => '',
  75 => 375,
  76 => '',
  77 => '',
  78 => '',
  79 => '',
  80 => '',
)
```

## note:

`$res` array could be different than shown as it was just the assumption but the format should be like this. Also, we can ignore the case sensitive.

## #

Basically, for just the first check, i could do it by looping in two foreach array as:

```
$res = array();
foreach($arr1 as $ak => $av){
    $match = false;
    foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
        if(!empty($av) && !empty($k)){
            if (preg_match("`\b" . preg_quote($av) . "\b`i", $k)) {
                array_push($res, $ar);
                $match= true;
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}
if(!$match) {
    array_push($res, '');
}
```

This work for check condition 1 but need to add for check 2, however, I am not sure if this is the efficient way as in future this array might be big especially `$arr2`.

### Update:

Sorry for inconvenience, here exact match means that the value from `$arr1` should be sub set of key of `$arr2` i.e, if there is a key `2nd level building` in `$arr2` then it should be considered the match of `2nd level`, however, `2nd levelbuilding` should not be the match.

Comment: The vagueness of the comparison requirement (e.g `2nd level`) is so wide that this looks more like a data structure issue than a programming issue. Basically the array key and value data is far too wide and varied for you to catch the required references. It feels like your arrays need normalising. Where do these arrays come from, can you edit the source data to be more consistent?

Comment: `IF the value don't match exactly,` This is very subjective; do you simply mean if the string if the value is *`IN`* the array key, in any part; such as `'try' ==> 'bigotry' ==> match`? If not; then what are your match criteria?

Comment: @Martin sorry for inconvenience I have made the update to the question. Actually, the array is from the history like `key of $arr2` belongs to the category with value of `$arr2`. So, based on those previous match, we need to make these new match which are in `$arr1`

Comment: Maybe I am off on this, but why not just use `if(array_intersect(array(), array())){`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop `$arr1`, and check its element that matched in keys of `$arr2`, and set the matched value to `$arr1`, set empty string to the element that cannot found in keys of `$arr2`:

```php
foreach($arr1 as $i => &$elem) {
    $val = getMatchedValue($arr2, $elem);
    $elem = ($val)? $val: $elem = '';
}

function getMatchedValue($hash, $elem) {
    $subs = explode(' ', $elem);
    $val = null;
    foreach($subs as $i => $sub) {
        if (isset($hash[$sub])) {
            if ($i == 0 || $val === $hash[$sub]) {
                $val = $hash[$sub];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        if (($i+1) == count($subs)) {
            if ($val && isset($hash[$sub]) && $val === $hash[$sub]) {
                return $val;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```